# Efficient probability tree branching

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

As an example, I have an array of branches and probabilities that looks like this:

```
paths = np.array([
[1, 0, 1.0],
[2, 0, 0.4],
[2, 1, 0.6],
[3, 1, 1.0],
[5, 1, 0.25],
[5, 2, 0.5],
[5, 4, 0.25],
[6, 0, 0.7],
[6, 5, 0.2],
[6, 2, 0.1]])
```

The columns are upper node, lower node, probability.
Here's a visual of the nodes:

```
        6
     /  |  \
    5   0   2
  / | \    / \
 1  2  4  0   1
 |  /\        |
 0 0  1       0
      |
      0
```

I want to be able to pick a starting node and output an array of the branches and cumulative probabilities, including all the duplicate branches. For example:
`start_node = 5` should return

```
array([
[5, 1, 0.25],
[5, 2, 0.5],
[5, 4, 0.25],
[1, 0, 0.25],
[2, 0, 0.2],
[2, 1, 0.3],
[1, 0, 0.3]])
```

Notice the `[1, 0, x]` branch is included twice, as it's fed by both the `[5, 1, 0.25]` branch and the `[2, 1, 0.3]` branch.

Here's some code I got working but it's far too slow for my application (millions of branches):

```
def branch(start_node, paths):
  output = paths[paths[:,0]==start_node]
  next_nodes = output

  while True:
    can_go_lower = np.isin(next_nodes[:,1], paths[:,0])

    if ~np.any(can_go_lower): break

    next_nodes_checked = next_nodes[can_go_lower]

    next_nodes = np.empty([0,3])
    for nodes in next_nodes_checked:
      to_append = paths[paths[:,0]==nodes[1]]
      to_append[:,2] *= nodes[2]
      next_nodes = np.append(next_nodes, to_append, axis=0)

    output = np.append(output, next_nodes, axis=0)

  return output
```

The branches are always higher to lower, therefor getting caught in circles isn't a concern. A way to vectorize the `for` loop and avoid the `append`s would be the best optimization, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing in numpy array lets' store graph in `dict`.

```
tree = {k:arr[arr[:, 0] == k] for k in np.unique(arr[:, 0])}
```

Make as set of nodes which are non-leaf:

```
non_leaf_nodes = set(np.unique(arr[:, 0]))
```

Now to find the branch and cumulative probability:

```
def branch(start_node, tree, non_leaf_nodes):
curr_nodes = [[start_node, start_node, 1.0]]    #(prev_node, starting_node, current_probability)
output = []
while True:
    next_nodes = []
    for _, node, prob in curr_nodes:
        if node not in non_leaf_nodes: continue
        subtree = tree[node]
        to_append = subtree.copy()
        to_append[:, 2] *= prob
        to_append = to_append.tolist()
        output += to_append
        next_nodes += to_append
    curr_nodes = next_nodes 
    if len(curr_nodes) == 0:
        break
return np.array(output)
```

Output:

```
>>> branch(5, tree, non_leaf_nodes)

array([
   [5.  , 1.  , 0.25],
   [5.  , 2.  , 0.5 ],
   [5.  , 4.  , 0.25],
   [1.  , 0.  , 0.25],
   [2.  , 0.  , 0.2 ],
   [2.  , 1.  , 0.3 ],
   [1.  , 0.  , 0.3 ]])
```

I am expecting it to work faster. Let me know.

Comment: What is `non_leaf_nodes`?

Comment: This method takes 11.7 s to run on a large data set (output ends up ~1M branches) with 10.5 s to build the dict and only 0.5 s to execute the actual function while my original function runs in 225 s.

Comment: I hope that's good enough for you. How many rows are there in your array? and how many unique values? In terms of graph, how many nodes are there?

Comment: This is sufficient, I can build the dict once and save it with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and then load it quickly for subsequent uses. The array is ~1.5M branches with ~9000 unique nodes.

Comment: @user11235 Okay. would you mind trying: `masks = arr[:, 0] == np.unique(arr[:, 0:1])[:, None]` and then `tree = {k:arr[mask] for k,mask in zip(np.unique(arr[:, 0:1]), masks)}` . I am just curious to know, in case you are busy let's close this discussion

Comment: Okay. This takes more time. Let's close this discussion.